# How can I have an optional abstract method to avoid empty functions?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I currently have an abstract class which i am extending to other controllers. I have a abstract function within the abstract class which takes the value and places it in the `__construct`.

```
abstract class Controller extends BaseController {
    abstract public function something();

    public function __construct(Request $request) {
        if (!is_null($this->something())){
            $this->global_constructor_usse = $this->something();
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that, on controllers that don't require this abstract function, I am having to place in the empty function.

```
class ControllerExample extends Controller {
  public function something(){
      return 'somethinghere';
  }
}
```

Is there anyway to making the abstract function optional, or have a default value?

```
class EmptyControllerExample extends Controller {
  public function something(){}
}
```

Comment: Give it a default body in the Controller abstract class, even if it's just `return;`. Then override it in child classes that need it. There is no such thing as an "optional abstract method".

Comment: I am getting the following error: `Abstract function App\Http\Controllers\Controller::Upload() cannot contain body` Can you give an example?

Comment: @JSG Because it can't be `abstract` AND have a body. If it has a body, you can't have `abstract` in the method sig.

Comment: So instead of `abstract function blah();` you would have `function blah() { ... }`.

Comment: If all of the controllers don't require it, do not abstract it. That is bad design. No client should be forced to depend on methods it does not use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Abstract functions in a parent class, should only be used if its required by your application to implement the following method in all controllers who inherits from it, clearly it is not the case.

In this case i would make a `trait`. Here you create a `trait` which can be implemented by the classes who needs it. Notice the `use` keyword usage, `use somethingTrait;`

```
trait SomethingTrait
{
    public function something()
    {
        echo "something called";
    }
}

class Controller
{
    use SomethingTrait;
    
    public function run()
    {
        $this->something();
    }
}
```

[phpfiddle link](http://phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%3C?php%5Cn%5Cntrait%20somethingTrait%5Cn%7B%5Cn%5Ctpublic%20function%20something()%5Cn%5Ct%7B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ctecho%20%22something%20called%22;%5Cn%5Ct%7D%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cnclass%20Controller%5Cn%7B%5Cn%5Ctuse%20somethingTrait;%5Cn%5Ct%5Cn%5Ctpublic%20function%20run()%5Cn%5Ct%7B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct$this-%3Esomething();%5Cn%5Ct%7D%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn(new%20Controller())-%3Erun();%5Cn%5Cn?%3E%5Cn)

Another aproach could be doing a `class` inheritance structure, if the controllers you want to implement the methods has something in common. Where you would implement your special method in `CrmController`, where you still would be able to create shared `methods` in the abstract controller.

```
                                 AbstractController
                                         |
                                    CrmController
                                         |
                                   CompanyController
```

For your question, 'Is there anyway to making the abstract function optional or have a default value?' No, and you are down the wrong path if you are trying to make abstract function optional. Hope my suggestions can help.

Comment: Yes, the trait it's indeed a good approach, the issue with that it's almost the same as abstract method because a trait could be easily scale to a code smell too.

Answer (score 4):

**It is not possible** to have a `abstract` method optional, as it is implied in PHP that all abstract methods must have an implementation.

There are legit use cases for *optional* abstract methods, yes: event handlers, metadata describers, etc. Unfortunately, you'll need to use regular, non-abstract methods with an empty body, and indicate in **PHPDoc** that they will do nothing unless extended.

Be wary, though: this can very quickly turn into code smell by diffusing a class responsability with their children. If you're dealing with generic events, you can look into [Laravel's own event system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/events), or the [Observer pattern](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-the-observer-pattern/) instead.